# authentication in windows and active directory

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory

what is the flow of how credentials are authenticated in windows when an username and password is typed on the machine? Does it has any database? how does it authenticates when the system is connected with an active directory?

Answer (score 0):

By default AD prefers using the Kerberos protocol. If you search for that, you'll find a ton of material about Kerberos. But here is a brief walk-through of how it works: https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/feature/Logging-on-to-Windows-using-Kerberos-Single-domain-environment